# The Accountant - How did they know?

Tags: the-accountant

How did the assassin's henchmen men know The Accountant was at the farmer's house?

The scene starts with him lying down in the back of his pickup, but it doesn't show if he saw someone but the next scene he is ready to shoot and the henchmen are in the farm house with the old couple.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### They follow him

We see him leave his house in his 'good' truck ( grey Ford) and we can see the villains start a blue Ford sedan in the distance which then starts up and tails him.

[image]